# PowerBI get last version and status

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to filter the information on Power BI by version and status. So we have the data below

```
Purchase   Version   Status
1239990    2         Signed
1239990    1         Cancelled
1239981    2         Submitted
1239981    1         Signed
```

We need to get the last version 'Signed'. So PowerBi should get the purchase **1239990** - v. **2** and **1239981** - v. **1**. Please some one have an idea how to get it?

Comment: You can simply use filter visual and add status column to it, then you can choose either of status and it filter the table as per the selection.

Comment: When you say 'the latest version of signed' -- do you also need the canceled and submitted rows to be in the table?

Comment: I need the max version value, where the status is signed. It possible exist 3 versions of the same purchase with status signed.